# Does jslint not look into functions within a file if they are marked as global?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

Same code as before but different question:

I have code like this:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*jslint vars: true */
/*global $, jQuery, adminModalDone, ajaxOnFailure, createModal, defineModal*/
/*global doAddSubmit, doResetTabs, mvcOnFailure*/
/*global onDialogDone, onDialogFail, submitHandler*/

function dialog($link) {
    "use strict";

    function doDialogAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html'
        })
            .done(onDialogDone)
            .fail(onDialogFail);
    }

    function onDialogDone(data) {
        content = data;
        if (content.match(/^[eE]rror/)) {
            mvcOnFailure(content);
        } else {
            defineModal();
            createModal();
            doAddSubmit();
            doResetTabs();
            adminModalDone();
        }
    }
}
```

Now jslint complains that most of the functions I have in OnDialogDone are not used. Because I defined onDialogDone as a global is it evaluated by jslint?

Comment: Why tell JSLint that `onDialogDone` is a global when it's defined in the same file? Use `global` for identifiers that are defined in *other* files, but used in this one.

Comment: because if it is declared after it's used then it complains that it is not declared :-(

Comment: That's not what `global` is for though, you're just tricking JSLint into thinking the function must be declared elsewhere.

Comment: @SamanthaJ - Move the declaration of `onDialogDone` before any code that calls it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/gMYQH/ JSLint: "Your JS code is valid."

Answer (score 1):

Rather than declaring `onDialogDone()` as a global, either of these two workarounds should remove the warning:

1. Swap the order of `onDialogDone()` and `doDialogAjax()` (as suggested by @James Allardice). JSLint expects all references to a function (or var name) to occur *lower* in the file than where it's declared.
2. If there are circular references that make it impossible to put things in that order (or organizationally you don't want to reorder things this way), you can use this trick:

   ```
   var onDialogDone;
   function doDialogAjax() {
       // call to onDialogDone() is in here - ok since below the var declaration
   }
   onDialogDone = function (data) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

There's a third option, disabling this warning entirely via the `undef: true` option, but I wouldn't recommend it. This particular warning is one of the best ones for catching typos and other guaranteed-crashes in your code. (Also, it looks like [JSLint has just removed the 'undef' option](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/68e56579115f443be4cae4990b4ce7e8c0112f28)).